# Finite sets are Jordan measurable because the outer jordan measure is equal to zero. Proof.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

Does anyone have an explanation as to why this statement correct or a link to the proof? I ask because this is counter intuitive to the definition of outer Jordan measure. We define the outer measure as

$$\mu_*(A)=\inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^m\mu(E_i):E_i\in P;A\subset \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{m}E_i\right \},$$ 
where the $E_i$ are elementary sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any point can be placed in a "half-open" cube of arbitrarily small volume.  All points have outer Jordan measure zero.  You can treat any finite set of points in an identical fashion.